# Is this for loop O(1) or O(n)?

Tags: code-analysis

There’s given an array[] = {0,2,6,...,1000000} with any size and a piece of code:

```
for i = 0 to size 
    print array[0]
```

Is this O(1) because it only prints the first item or O(n) because it prints it n (size) time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is O(n), where n is the size of the array given.

Let's just say printing an element of the array takes 1 second.

If the array has 1 element, the program will print the first element 1 time, so it takes 1 second to run the program.

If the array has 10 elements, the program will print the first element 10 times, so it takes 10 seconds to run the program.

If the array has 100 elements, the program will print the first element 100 times, so it takes 100 seconds to run the program.

The time it takes to run the program increases linearly with the size of the array. Hence the algorithm is O(n).

Answer (score 1):

It is O(n).

Since this `for` loop is from 0 to **size**, so this `for` is O(n). And inside `for`, it `print array[0]` which is O(1).

So the whole segment becomes O(n) x O(1) which is also O(n).

It prints the first item **for n times**, which results in O(n).

For example, think of this simple assignment code below:

```
for i = 0 to size
    a = array[0]
```

It also gets the first item **for n times**, and it is obviously O(n) (ignore any compiler optimization).